# PostgreSQL 11: Replace function body by users from the same group

Tags: postgresql, permissions, functions, replace

In the [documentation of `CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createfunction.html) is stated that ''You must own the function to replace it (this includes being a member of the owning role).''

Two questions:

1. I don't understand what exactly the ''this includes being a member of the owning role'' part means.
2. Is it possible to have multiple users (non superusers) that can modify the body of the same set of functions? I have a user which creates the functions, tables etc (Liquibase user) and I want to add a debug user which should have the permission to modify functions created by the first user in order to test some assumptions or hotfixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example setup:

```
CREATE ROLE function_creator;

CREATE USER radu;
CREATE USER ion;

GRANT function_creator TO radu, ion; -- this is 'being a member of the owning role'

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA here_live_the_functions TO function_creator;
```

Then, when you create functions:

```
SET ROLE TO function_creator;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...;
```

After all this, you and `ion` will be able to change (redefine) the function, which is owned by `function_creator`.

If you need the debug user, you can add one more level:

```
CREATE ROLE debugger;

GRANT function_creator TO debugger;

-- and instead of granting function_creator to the actual users, do 
GRANT debugger TO radu, ion;
```